# How do I show/hide images in column headers of c# datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has many columns, 2 of them sortable, Date & Amount. My code works in terms of reordering the rows (asc-to-desc, desc-to-asc) whenever either column is clicked. BUT, I have 3 icons in each column header - an up arrowhead, a down arrowhead, and a default icon showing both.

How can I get the default icon to show on page load, and the up arrowhead only to show when the order is ascending, the down when descending? Just now I have all 3 icons showing, and any attempt to fix this problem throws an error.

Here is the relevant part of the datagrid (showing the Amount column):

```
     <asp:datagrid id="dgCurrentRequests" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Names="Verdana"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyField="RequestID" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="OnSort">
                            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#006699"></HeaderStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="Branch"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="AccountantName" HeaderText="Requested By"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Supplier" HeaderText="Pay To"></asp:BoundColumn>


<asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="DisplayAmount">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton id="DisplayAmount" runat="server" Text="Amount"  
                                        CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="DisplayAmount"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <img runat="server" id="AmountAscending" src="..\images\asc.png" />
                                <img runat="server" id="AmountDefault" src="..\images\default.png" />
                                <img runat="server" id="AmountDescending" src="..\images\desc.png" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <itemtemplate>
                                <asp:Label id="DisplayAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DisplayAmount") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

And here is the codebehind for reordering the grid:

```
 public void FillCurrentRequests()
        {
            Accountant theAccountant=(Accountant)Session["Accountant"];
            ArrayList requests = new ArrayList();
            requests = theAccountant.GetExternalRoylineRequests(dbConnString, "Pending", (string)ViewState["sortColumn"], (string)ViewState["sortDirection"], 100);

            dgCurrentRequests.DataSource = requests;
            dgCurrentRequests.DataBind();

        }

        public void OnSort(Object sender, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((string) ViewState["sortColumn"]).Equals(e.SortExpression))
            {
                if (((string) ViewState["sortDirection"]) == "ASC")
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "DESC";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
            }

            ViewState["sortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;

            FillCurrentRequests();
        }




I have attempted to declare the images then use them in a method to set the default icon, but it throws a SystemNullException:

        protected Image AmountAscending;
        protected Image AmountDefault;
        protected Image AmountDescending;
        protected Image DateRequestedAscending;
        protected Image DateRequestedDefault;
        protected Image DateRequestedDescending;

//

        public void ResetSortOrder()
        {
            AmountAscending.Visible = false;
            ...
        }
```

It is as if the application can't see that the cs file entities 'AmountAscending' etc are the id's of those images in the aspx file.

Help please! How can I use those images within the aspx.cs page?